# How to make clickable anchor in contentEditable div?

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have following code:

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
  Blah blah <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> Blah blah
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeVpe/)

Is there a way to make this `a` clickable, not editable, without moving anchor outside that div?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just wrap the link in another div, like so:

```
<div contentEditable="true">

    <div contentEditable="false">
            Bla bla <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> Bla bla
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: I would prefer if anchors were editable when I click outside of a anchor and inside div but this way is sufficient. Thanks

Comment: The anchor text isn't editable here. Would it be possible to make the link clickable while still allowing the anchor's text to be edited?

Comment: add contentEditable="false" to <a> is better. `<a href="http://google.com" contentEditable="false">Google</a>`

Answer (score 21):

Make the link itself uneditable (works at least on HTML5):

`<a contenteditable="false" href="http....... >`

Answer (score 7):

As far as I am aware, there is no way of doing this without programming it yourself using Javascript. The simple way to do this is to disable and reenable `contentEditable` whenever the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed. So when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed, the link is clickable, otherwise not. This means you can still edit the content of the link. This functionality is similar to that of Microsoft Word, IIRC.

The code might look something like this:

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 17) {          // when ctrl is pressed
        content.contentEditable = false; // disable contentEditable
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 17) {          // when ctrl is released
        content.contentEditable = true;  // reenable contentEditable
    }
}, false);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeVpe/6/)

Comment: In your example, the link inside the contentEditable div isn't clickable. I hope it would be possible to fix this.

Comment: The example worked just fine for me, although I am using SeaMonkey and IE may not handle those events properly...

Comment: Works for me too (Vivaldi).

Comment: This breaks Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V

Answer (score 1):

To get a clickable and editable link, I put an onclick-command in the link. 
Example:

```
<a contenteditable="true" href="necessary?" onclick="document.location = 'www.xy.com';" ...>
    <img src="image.jpg" draggable="true" ...>
</a>
```

Disadvantages have been:
In IE the link had to be clicked twice.
In mobile Safari the keyboard was shown (Could be hidden with Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

The links inside the `contenteditable` element can be changed to work with `mousedown` event, instead of a `click` event, because the `click` event is waiting for the `mouseup` event to fire, and by that time, the field already has focus and therefore links would not "work" (because the field is now in a special "edit" mode).

### Inline `onmousedown`:

```html
<div contentEditable>
    Blah blah <a onmousedown="window.location.href=this.href" href="http://google.com">Google</a> Blah blah
</div>
```

### Delegated event:

Of course this is a crude implementation, and you can enhance it by distinguishing between left & right mouse clicks and also extract completely remove the inline event and use a delegated event:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onContentEditableLinksMouseDown)

function onContentEditableLinksMouseDown(e) {
  if( e.target.closest('[contentEditable="true"]') && e.target.href && e.button === 0 )
    window.location.href = e.target.href
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true" tabIndex='-1'>
    Blah blah <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> Blah blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a class to the link e.g.

```
Bla bla <a class="inner-link" href="http://google.com">Google</a> Bla bla
```

Then catch the click event:

```
$("body").on("click", ".inner-link", function(e) {
    var the_link = $(this).attr("href");
    window.open(the_link, "_blank");
});
```