# Add text after the element rather than in the element in editable div - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true"><a>Hello</a></div>
```

When the cursor is just after `Hello`, it appends new text in the `<a>` element. But it should add new text after the `<a>` element. How to do this?

Comment: I believe there is no need of JS code from my side cuz i dont know the solution to my problem.

 The problem is that the `<a>` tag as this as style property of  `color:#4faacb`. So when cursor is just after `Hello`, the new text I enter also comes in `#4faacb`. So i want the new text, to be added after the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this may not be the best solution, but you can add another div inside the content editable, set this one to false tho.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <div contentEditable="false">
        <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    </div>
    Content here -- Wont change your link.
</div>
```

Comment: Good approach, but I can't opt for `contenteditable = false` in the a tag, due to some other feature on my site

Comment: By some other feature, but it must not change because of writing text

Comment: Don't know how I would do it..here's the closest question that has a few detailed answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059211/how-to-make-clickable-anchor-in-contenteditable-div