# Adding link inside a DIV that looks like a Text Area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added a DIV that looks like a text area, so that i could display hyper links inside that. The problem am facing is that, the hyper link is displayed properly in a text area look & feel DIV, but it's not clickable.

HTML:

```
<div id="input" contenteditable><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 398px;    
}
```

How can i make this hyper link clickable and navigate to the URL?

Comment: What should happen when someone clicks the link? Should it move the cursor there or open the link?

Comment: @Kris check this jsfiddle, should provide what you want http://jsfiddle.net/y6dkwrov/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've attached the same question asked previously. The anchor tag is `contenteditable`, and thus not clickable. You could wrap the anchor tag in another div that takes `contenteditable` off.

[How to make clickable anchor in contentEditable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059211/how-to-make-clickable-anchor-in-contenteditable-div)

Comment: The problem now is that, the DIV is no longer editable. I want multiple HREF's to be present in this DIV by separating them with a comma. So along with the existing href's that's already in DIV, user should be able to edit and add more href's.

Comment: That really gets back to @bookcasey's question. Do you want the anchor to link when you click it, or to put a cursor there when you click it, it's pretty much either/or.

Comment: The text filed/DIV should have something like this = "Google, Yahoo, MSN, .." The content with in double quotes is what's displayed in DIV. Now if user places cursor on top of "Google" and click on it, then the page will navigate to Google home page, if user places cursor on ".." then it should show a blinking "|" that will tell the user that it's possible to enter some text here. Is this possible.