# Forced to edit link instead of going to link in editable table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which allows me to edit a cell, but the problem is that when I want to click on the link, it forces me to edit instead. I want to be able to edit only when I click on the pen icon, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table border="1" style="width:100px" style="height:99px" style="margin:0 
auto">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="datamapname">
     <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
     <a id="dm" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Sample</a> 
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
//--->make div editable > start
$(document).on('click', '.row_data', function(event) 
{
  //Remove pencil icon.
  $(this).find('i.fa-pencil').remove();

  //Remove link
  $("#dm").removeAttr('href');

  event.preventDefault(); 
  if($(this).attr('edit_type') == 'button')
  {
    return false; 
  }

  //make div editable
  $(this).closest('div').attr('contenteditable', 'true');

  //add bg css
  $(this).addClass('bg-warning').css('padding','5px');
  $(this).focus();
  $(this).attr('original_entry', $(this).html());
})  
//--->make div editable > end

// --> save single field data > start
$(document).on('focusout', '.row_data', function(event) 
{
  event.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).attr('edit_type') == 'button')
  {
    return false; 
  }

  //Add pencil icon back
  $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>');

  //Add link back
  $("#dm").attr('href','https://www.google.com/');      
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89zgd1ry/

Comment: Did you try , return false when clicked on the input?

Comment: Looks to me that you're substantially overcomplicating things by adding/removing nodes and usin contenteditable.  You can achieve the same with a hidden `<input>` and toggling the input/link.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the anchor tag in another `div` and set `contentEditable="false"`.

Try to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059211/how-to-make-clickable-anchor-in-contenteditable-div)

Answer (score 0):

> when I want to click on the link, it forces me to edit instead.

This is because you click handler is on the parent row_data div

> I want to be able to edit only when I click on the pen icon

Change

```
$(document).on('click', '.row_data',
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.row_data>i.fa-pencil',
```

`this` will then refer to the icon so you'll have to make appropriate changes, eg:

```
$(this).find(".fa-pencil").remove();
```

becomes

```
var row = $(this).closest(".row_data");
$(this).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
$('#dm').click(function( e ){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

And

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa-pencil',...
```